# Difference Between monocular video and stereo video?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, video, video-compression

What is the difference between monocular video and stereo video ,as i am studying about motion tracking i need to know the meaning of these two things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monocular video is taken using a single camera.  Stereo video is taken using two cameras side-by-side, producing two video streams.  That's pretty much it.

A stereo video pair allows depth measurement, so you can find out how far away things are.  However, this is not an easy task for complex scenes.

Comment: Can the camera move during the video?

Comment: @frank Yes, if the camera is on a robot or vehicle.